# why does this queue does not work properly with binary tree nodes.Works perfectly for integers and primintive data

Tags: tree, queue

I am trying to traverse a tree in level order . For that i need a queue. I am trying to implement the queue by using link list . However my turbo c is not showing the correct output . Online compilers show segmentation error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct treenode{
int info;
struct treenode *left,*right;
};

struct node{ 
struct treenode* info;
struct node* next;
};

typedef struct treenode* treenode;
typedef struct node* node;

node header=NULL;

treenode newnode(int x)
{
treenode temp;
temp=(treenode)(malloc(sizeof(struct treenode)));
temp->info=x;
temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
return temp;
}
void enqueue(treenode x)
{
node temp,current;
temp->info=x;
temp->next=NULL;
if(header==NULL)
header=temp;

else
{
current=header;
while(current->next!=NULL)
{
current=current->next;

}
current->next=temp; 


}
} 

int main() 
{
treenode root;
root=newnode(1);
root->left=newnode(2);
root->right=newnode(3);
root->left->left=newnode(4);
root->left->right=newnode(5);
root->right->left=newnode(6);
root->right->right=newnode(7);


enqueue(root);
printf("%d",header->info->info);  //expected value 1   
enqueue(root->left);
printf("%d",header->next->info->info);    //expected value 2
printf("%d",header->next->next->info->info);//expected value NULL 
return 0;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Well you might work on the formatting to assist people in helping you.

The first thing you should focus on is:

```
temp->info=x;
```

which gives when run a segfault due to bad access (a NULL pointer, right?)

I used following reformated code to get an idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct treenode{
    int info;
    struct treenode *left,*right;
};

struct node{ 
    struct treenode* info;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct treenode* treenode;
typedef struct node* node;

node header=NULL;

treenode newnode(int x) {
    treenode temp;
    temp = (treenode)(malloc(sizeof(struct treenode)));
    temp->info=x;
    temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
    return temp;
}
void enqueue(treenode x) {
    node temp,current;
    temp->info=x;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(header==NULL) {
        header=temp;
    }
    else {
        current=header;
        while(current->next!=NULL) {
            current=current->next;
        }
        current->next=temp;
    }
} 

int main() {
    treenode root;
    root=newnode(1);
    root->left=newnode(2);
    root->right=newnode(3);
    root->left->left=newnode(4);
    root->left->right=newnode(5);
    root->right->left=newnode(6);
    root->right->right=newnode(7);


    enqueue(root);
    printf("%d",header->info->info);  //expected value 1
    enqueue(root->left);
    printf("%d",header->next->info->info);    //expected value 2
    printf("%d",header->next->next->info->info);  //expected value NULL
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. You're welcome and thanks for checkiing. So the anwsern is accepted?